# How to find radius of convergence of given series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Consider the series
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x}{5}+\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{x^3}{5^2}+\frac{x^4}{3^3}+\frac{x^5}{5^3}+\cdots$$

I want to find the radius of convergence of this series.

$\textbf{Here is my work}$

I tried to figure out $a_n$ for the given power series but it did not work. 
$$a_n=3^{-\frac{n+1}{2}|\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})|} \times5^{-\frac{n}{2}|\sin(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2})|}$$
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n
}
$$
Also I thought about finding radius of convergence separately for even and odd terms but I am not sure how is that going to help.

Comment: Intuitively, once $n$ gets large enough we will have $\left(\frac 35\right)^n \ll x$ so the terms with $3$ in the denominator will dominate over the terms with $5$.  I would ignore the terms with $5$ as a start and try to solve the problem, then justify that the terms with $5$ do not matter.  When you are worried about convergence as opposed to the value of the limit you only care about terms very far out.  The early terms can change the limit a lot, but there are only finitely many of them so they cannot make the sum diverge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series:
$$
S=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x}{5}+\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{x^3}{5^2}+\frac{x^4}{3^3}+\frac{x^5}{5^3}+...
$$

Can be expressed as:
$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {a_k}
$$
Where:
$$
a_k=\frac{x^{k-1}}{3^k}+\frac{x^{k}}{5^k}
$$
Now, testing the convergency:
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left|{\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}}\right|=
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left|{\frac{\frac{x^{k}}{3^{k+1}}+\frac{x^{k+1}}{5^{k+1}}}{\frac{x^{k-1}}{3^k}+\frac{x^{k}}{5^k}}}\right|=
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left|{\frac{\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}+\frac{x}{5^{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{3^k x}+\frac{1}{5^k}}}\right|=
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left|{\frac{1+x\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{k+1}}{\frac{3}{x}+3\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k}}\right|=...
$$
$$
...=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{x}{3}\right|<1
$$

Hence, we get:
$$
\left|x\right|<3
$$

And finally radius of convergence is $r=3$.